# How to draw image without edges

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

does somebody knows, how to show image in visual studio in imagebutton without edges?

image>

[image]

My code>
CSS

```
.imageButtonCSS {
width: 15px; height: 15px;
margin-right: 5px;
padding: 0px;
background: url("../Images/delete.png");
}
```

C#

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
imageButton .ID = "1";
imageButton .CssClass = "imageButtonCSS ";
tableCell.Controls.Add(imageButton);
```

Comment: Without edges ? means no border..? can you describe in more

Comment: You could try `border: 0 none;` in your .imageButtonCSS rule.  I can't see the problem. And I can't replicate it because I don't have visual studio on this machine.

Comment: Janty: I add picture of this image and I want to show as circle, not as square.. 
John: it doesnt work...

Comment: If it just X icon I think it's better to found an exist one  .

Answer (score 2):

Use below-
    `img, button{outline:0, border: none;}`
Also to use round corners, you can use-
    `button.imageButtonCSS {border-radius:50%;}`

Comment: Border radius does not support IE

Comment: it works in IE-9 or greater... and for mozila old versions and chrome support try  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;

Answer (score 0):

You can add or replace image and then check, the edges are in image file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a border-radius to your CSS class if you want to remove the edges.

Here's an [link](http://border-radius.com/) where you can play with the border-radius property.

And here is the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

And here is the browser support: caniuse.com/border-radius

Comment: border-radius doesnt make effects on IE.. :/

Comment: Doesn't apply to all IE version. IE9+ apparently supports it